# Null check on modal attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller defined as:

```
    public ModelAndView execute(final HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute final UploadFormBean anObject) {
    //some code
}
```

My question is on null check for `anObject`. Does this make sense: `anObject != null`. Please explain your answer also.

Answer (score 2):

`anObject` will never be null, since Spring MVC will instantiate it.

Here is a quote from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

> Given the above example where can the Pet instance come from? There are several options:
>
> ...
>
> - It may be instantiated using its default constructor.

Comment: Yeah. Same thoughts. There was a legacy code and wanted to see if my thinking was correct.

Comment: I'm trying to find where is this documented, will update my answer with reference if I do...